# How do I add a custom command-line argument to Python Locust?

Tags: python, locust

How do I add a custom command-line argument to Python Locust 0.7.2, then retrieve its value?

I want to specify a number:

```
locust --my-argument 6
```

Then in my script, I want to retrieve the value, with something like:

```
my_argument = ??.options.my_argument
```

I have found this in locust/main.py

```
def main():
    parser, options, arguments = parse_options()
```

But it appears that the parse_options() function doesn't look externally for any additional arguments.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass custom parameters to a locust test class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951458/how-to-pass-custom-parameters-to-a-locust-test-class)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment.

```
c:\locust>set env_test = ekomut
c:\locust>locust ...

import os
....
 def on_start(self):
        print("Variable:"+os.environ.get("env_test "))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could edit the file (or fork the project) to enable additional optional arguments. It is open source and has a permissive license, after all.