# how to pass custom parameters to a locust test class?

Tags: locust

I'm currently passing custom parameters to my load test using environment variables.  For example, my test class looks like this:

```python
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import os

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def login(self):
        test_dir = os.environ['BASE_DIR']
        auth=tuple(open(test_dir + '/PASSWORD').read().rstrip().split(':')) 
        self.client.request(
           'GET',
           '/myendpoint',
           auth=auth
        )   

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
```

Then I'm running my test with:

```
locust -H https://myserver --no-web --clients=500 --hatch-rate=500 --num-request=15000 --print-stats --only-summary
```

Is there a more `locust` way that I can pass custom parameters to the `locust` command line application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nowadays it is possible to add custom parameters to Locust (it wasnt possible when this question was originally asked, at which time using env vars was probably the best option).

Since version 2.2, custom parameters are even forwarded to the workers in a distributed run.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#custom-arguments

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, events


@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def _(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--my-argument", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_MY_ARGUMENT", default="", help="It's working")
    # Set `include_in_web_ui` to False if you want to hide from the web UI
    parser.add_argument("--my-ui-invisible-argument", include_in_web_ui=False, default="I am invisible")


@events.test_start.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    print("Custom argument supplied: %s" % environment.parsed_options.my_argument)


class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        print(f"my_argument={self.environment.parsed_options.my_argument}")
        print(f"my_ui_invisible_argument={self.environment.parsed_options.my_ui_invisible_argument}")
```

Answer (score 17):

You could use like `env <parameter>=<value> locust <options>` and use `<parameter>` inside the locust script to use its value

E.g.,
`env IP_ADDRESS=100.0.1.1 locust -f locust-file.py --no-web --clients=5 --hatch-rate=1 --num-request=500` and use IP_ADDRESS inside the locust script to access its value which is 100.0.1.1 in this case.

Answer (score -3):

It is not recommended to run locust in command line if you want to test in high concurrency. As in `--no-web` mode, you can only use one CPU core, so that you can not make full use of your test machine.

Back to your question, there is not another way to pass custom parameters to `locust` in command line.

Comment: you can use locust in master/workers mode